# How to open new screen in app with swipeable layout android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I've made my app in android but it doesn't work - when I click on the button it doesn't open new screen of my app in android, but it show's error and end my app. If anybody can help me, and show what I am doing wrong, I will be very hapy. Here's my code:
MainActivity

```
package pl.mylaw.mylaw2;
import pl.mylaw.mylaw2.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs = { "Cywilne", "Karne", "Admini...", "Inne" };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
}
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }
});
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
@Override 
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}   
public void kpa_przejscie( View v)      
{
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass( this, KpaActivity.class);
startActivity( intent);
}
}
```

KpaActivty.class

```
package pl.mylaw.mylaw2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
public class KpaActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kpa);
}
public void kpa_powrot( View v)
{
    finish();
}
}
```

and part of Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="pl.mylaw.mylaw2.KpaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kp" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

and the last one part of button definition:

08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.mylaw.mylaw2/pl.mylaw.mylaw2.KpaActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #6: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #6: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5297)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:5418)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.(RelativeLayout.java:1064)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:933)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:69)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:741)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at pl.mylaw.mylaw2.KpaActivity.onCreate(KpaActivity.java:13)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
08-22 00:49:26.558: E/AndroidRuntime(686):  ... 11 more

here are LogCat errors:)

Comment: What is the error? Please post the complete logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs, it seems that some xml attributed associated with the class KpaActivity doesn't have the property "layout_width".
"You must supply a layout_width attribute."

Try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="KOdeks" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it still doesnt work :( i think the problem is not a xml code but something diffrent

Comment: I don't know. But based on the logs I would look at all xml file. When i tested your code, it had several errors. Maybe there are more errors in other xml.